# How to handle Optional Codable List in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I am using following property in a model that confirms to Codable

```
let tasks = List<Task>()
```

tasks store optional data but realm don't allow for optional lists. However decoding/encoding throws exception when the API returns nil for tasks property.

I am thinking about doing manual coding and decoding for all models but that would be too much because I have too many properties in each model. So is there any work around for such issue?

Comment: It would be better to separate "transport" `Codable`s and `Realm` types. And then manually map one to another.

Comment: How can you have *too many properties in each model*? Too many for what?

Comment: @Jay I have about 20 properties in each model so I don't want to go through all properties just to handle one property issue